Trying to make an Isometric game without isometric tile rendering
I am a high school student programming a pygame game for a school project that is due in about a week and a half from now and my problem is if I am able to create an isometric game but instead of tile rendering since I am unable to find a comprehensive tutorial on pygame about it, I would somehow be able to just use a background that resembles a rendered isometric grid similar but not exactly like the image below and manipulate the control arrow keys of the sprite to look like it is an isometric movement. Would this be possible or would it look tacky and not good?
enter image description here
I've only made the isometric grid and I'm in the works of attempting to manipulate the sprite control movement.

Include some code. Your question currently doesn't show research effort

Yes It's possible. But you will still need isometric grid math. So why not also do tile rendering but that's not the question I guess. So answering:

control arrow keys of the sprite to look like it is an isometric movement

We can have a grid and place the sprite on the grid with gridx and gridy coordinates. Don't forget these are not the actual screen coordinates. Then we can use the generic isometric view formula to cast the grid coordinates to our screen using this formula:
self.x = (self.gridx - self.gridy)*TILE_WIDTH_HALF
self.y = (self.gridx + self.gridy)*TILE_HEIGHT_HALF

Then rest is usual pygame stuff:
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

fps = 60
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

width, height = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

TILE_WIDTH  = 16
TILE_WIDTH_HALF = TILE_WIDTH/2
TILE_HEIGHT = 8
TILE_HEIGHT_HALF = TILE_HEIGHT/2

class Player():
    def __init__(self,gridx,gridy,image):
        self.gridx = gridx
        self.gridy = gridy
        self.image = image
        self.x = (self.gridx-self.gridy)*TILE_WIDTH_HALF
        self.y = (self.gridx+self.gridy)*TILE_HEIGHT_HALF
        
    def update(self,udlr):
        u,d,l,r = udlr #extract key info
        if u:
            self.gridy -= 1
        elif d:
            self.gridy += 1
        elif l:
            self.gridx -= 1
        elif r:
            self.gridx += 1   
            
        self.x = (self.gridx-self.gridy)*TILE_WIDTH_HALF
        self.y = (self.gridx+self.gridy)*TILE_HEIGHT_HALF
        
    def render(self,screen):
        screen.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))

player_img = pygame.image.load('player.png').convert_alpha()
player = Player(30,30,player_img)

# Game loop.
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    inputs = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    #udlr -> up,down,left,right
    inputs_udlr = (inputs[K_UP],inputs[K_DOWN],inputs[K_LEFT],inputs[K_RIGHT])
    player.update(inputs_udlr) #Update player with given udlr inputs
    player.render(screen) #Render player at screen with its x,y
    pygame.display.flip() #Update everything
    fpsClock.tick(fps) #Steady fps

Useful resource for isometric game development. Isometric Tiles Math
